# Javascript: Mask only first 12 digits of credit card number on "onkeyup" event

Tags: javascript, html, css

- I want to mask first 12 digits as * on "onkeyup" event and leave next
  4 digits as it is.
- The below function is masking first 12 digits but all at once on
  "onblur" event.
- I have already tried allmost answers from stackoverflow but none of them helped me out.

```js
function formatCardNumber(element) {
 if(element.value.length > 14) {
  var position = element.selectionStart;
  element.value = element.value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/^(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)$/, "$1 $2 $3 $4");
  if(element.value.length != 19) {
   element.setSelectionRange(position, position);
  }
 }
 else {
  element.value = element.value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ');
 } 
}

function showCardValue() {
 document.getElementById("cardNo").value = document.getElementById("cardNoSafe").value;
}

function hideCardValue(val) {
 document.getElementById("cardNoSafe").value = val;
 var len = val.length;
 if (len >= 14) {
  const regex = /\d{4}(?= \d{1})/g;
  const substr = "****";
  document.getElementById("cardNo").value = val.replace(regex, substr);
 }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="cardNo" placeholder="Enter Card Number" onfocus="showCardValue()" onblur="hideCardValue(this.value)" onkeypress="formatCardNumber(this)" maxlength="19">
  <input id="cardNoSafe" value="" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i cant offer you the whole solution, but this should be enough for you to adapt it to your own work including the of you asked behavior :)

```js
function hideCardValue(element){
  var tmpval = element.value;
  if(tmpval.length <12){
    var re = /\d{1}/;
    document.getElementById("cardNoSafe").value += tmpval.replace(new RegExp('\\*', 'g'),"");
    
    document.getElementById("cardNo").value = tmpval.replace(/\d{1}/,"*");
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="cardNo" placeholder="Enter Card Number" onkeyup="hideCardValue(this);" maxlength="19">
  <input id="cardNoSafe" value="" style="display:true;">
</div>
```

I made the hidden Box visible in order to see the safed values.

Hope this helps ;)

Greetings

Comment: thanks buddy but I'm in search of complete solution, partial solution I've got already but thats not enough

Comment: oh, i figured you only need that part. Where is your problem exactly to implement this? Maybe i can give you a little more help

Comment: your answer is masking only after 4 digits are typed, what I want is every single digit should be masked when it is typed till length 12 and rest should be visible

Comment: Yes this is much better, although formatCardNumber() function is failing with this snippet but that I can take care of, thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: Always happy if i can help, enjoy mate :)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the input into 4 separate inputs while each of them is defined as password (only last one is plain text).

This way you'll be able to hide most of the number and show only the last 4 digits.

Of course you'll need to prettify it with some css :)

```js
function moveToNext(curr, next) {
  if ($(curr).val().length === 4) {
    next.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<input id="part1" type="password" maxlength="4" onkeyup="moveToNext(part1, part2)"/>
<input id="part2" type="password" maxlength="4" onkeyup="moveToNext(part2, part3)"/>
<input id="part3" type="password" maxlength="4" onkeyup="moveToNext(part3, part4)"/>
<input id="part4" type="text" maxlength="4"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alon for answering but I want to use single input box instead.

Comment: This way I think you can't paste the whole number from the clipboard.